# How to show "Your Virtual Hosts" list in wamp 2.5 homepage

Tags: php, apache, wamp

There are plenty of instruction on what settings to change to show the Virtual Hosts list in the wamp homepage, however upon inspecting index.php in C://wamp/www there appeared to be no code in here to show the Virtual Hosts no matter what the settings were elsewhere. So, I have added some code in myself to show this list and thought it might help others who want to do the same.

This requires your httpd-vhosts.conf file to have entries such as the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/website_folder_name"
     ServerName Website_Name         #<----------This is the what index.php uses
     <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/website_folder_name">
          AllowOverride All
          Require local
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, in C://wamp/www/index.php make the following changes:

After this line (line 65) $wampserverVersion = str_replace('"','',$result[1]);

Add:

```
$wampVHostsFile = $server_dir.'bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf';
if (!is_file($wampVHostsFile))
     die ('Unable to open Virtual Hosts file, please change path in index.php file');
$fp = fopen($wampVHostsFile,'r');
$wampVHostsFileContents = fread ($fp, filesize ($wampVHostsFile));
fclose ($fp);

$vHosts = "";
$result = array(1=>array(1=>786));
while(! empty($result)) {
     preg_match('|ServerName (.*)|',$wampVHostsFileContents,$result, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $result[1][1]);
     array_key_exists(1, $result) ? $vHosts .= '<li><a href="'.($suppress_localhost ? 'http://' : '').$result[1][0].'">'.$result[1][0].'</a></li>' : null;
}

if (empty($vHosts))
     $vHosts = "<li>No Virtual Hosts</li>\n";;
```

Then scroll to the bottom of the file and edit $pageContents containing the html. I decided I didn't want the list of aliases so comment out this code:

```
<div class="third right">
     <h2>{$langues[$langue]['txtAlias']}</h2>
     <ul class="aliases">
          ${aliasContents}          
     </ul>
</div>
```

And replace with this code:

```
<div class="third right">
     <h2>Your Virtual Hosts</h2>
     <ul class="aliases">
          ${vHosts}
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a question and it is not the correct solution either. For the correct solution see this doc on the WAMPServer forum http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,124482 and look for the section entitled **Now there is one more thing.**

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I still couldn't get the virtual hosts list. There's no code in index.php to even show the virtual hosts. Hence why I changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

How do I turn the `WAMPServer2.5` *My Virtual Hosts* menu on?

- Make a backup of the \wamp\wampmanager.tpl file, just in case you make a mistake, its a very important file.
- Edit the \wamp\wampmanager.tpl
- Find this parameter `;WAMPPROJECTSUBMENU`, its in the '[Menu.Left]' section.
- Add this new parameter `;WAMPVHOSTSUBMENU` either before or after the `;WAMPPROJECTSUBMENU` parameter.
- Save the file.
- Now *left click* the wampmanager icon, and select `Refresh`. If this does not add the menu, 'exit' and restart wampmanager.

**Note**
The new menu will only appear if you already have some Virtual Hosts defined! Otherwise you will see no difference until you define a Virtual Host or two.

Oh and if its @Bollis reading this, undo all the unnecessary changes you made to index.php

Comment: I have already tried the above and it did not work. Do you have any other suggestions @RiggsFolly? Thanks.

Comment: Did you also read Otomatics port on that thread, it describes some changes to four other files in the system.

Comment: Yes, I made all those changes and did many searches and tried everything I could find, but the virtual hosts still would not show.